# How to select the most frequent value for each group within two tables?

Tags: sql, select, subquery, group

I have two tables and I want to select the most ordered (amount) product for each shipmentType (see result table)

shipment table

| id | shipmentTyp | amount | productID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | S | 7 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 12 | 3 |
| 4 | T | 15 | 2 |
| 5 | T | 7 | 1 |
| 6 | T | 4 | 3 |
| 7 | A | 1 | 3 |
| 8 | S | 78 | 2 |

Products table

| productID | productName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | P1 |
| 2 | P2 |
| 3 | P3 |

Result table

| shipmentType | productName | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | P3 | 12 |
| S | P2 | 78 |
| T | P2 | 15 |

Comment: What is your DBMS product and version? Oracle? MuSQL?

Comment: DBMS is IBM Db2

Answer (score 1):

It seems a simple ROW_NUMBER() problem to me -

```
SELECT 
    SH.shipmentType, P.productName, SH.amount
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         shipmentType, amount, productID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY shipmentType ORDER BY amount DESC) RN
     FROM 
         shipment) SH
JOIN 
    Products P ON SH.productID = P.productID
WHERE 
    RN = 1;
```

Comment: thanx but what is RN, it could not resolve it

Comment: @ahm5, Fixed now.